# reading two MySql queries on c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql

SELECT @gb FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor =@ff I'm new with c# and it's my first programm.
I'm trying to connect mysql server and run a query.
Then, I want to take he results of the first query and run another query with them.
the first query works good, the second mysqldataread doesnt work and i cant understand why. (i'm using vs 2013).

code:

```
myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT GB,Form_Factor FROM devices WHERE Serial_Number = @Sn";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sn", Sn);

connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    textBox2.Text = reader["GB"].ToString();
    textBox3.Text = reader["Form_Factor"].ToString();
}
reader.Close();
connect.Close();


string gb = textBox2.Text;
string ff = textBox3.Text;
MySqlCommand myCommand2 = connect.CreateCommand();
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gb", gb);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ff", ff);
myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT @gb FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor =@ff ";

connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

reader2.Read();

if (reader2.Read())
{
    string command = reader2["@gb"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(command);
}

if (reader2.Read() == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("read failed!");
}

reader2.Close();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: Can you provide any error logging or further debug information? "Doesn`t work" is hard to work with

Comment: i put  if (reader2.Read() == false) and i got  "read failed! and not MessageBox.Show(command).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can guess `@gb` isn't an existing field in parameters table , thats why you aren;t getting any results in second query. Also using statement is a good practise when messing with sqlcommands:

```
myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT @gb FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor =@ff ";
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gb", gb);
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ff", ff);
     using (connect)
           {
             connect.Open();
             MySqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

                while (reader2.Read())
                {
                    string command = reader2[0].ToString();
                   MessageBox.Show(command);
                }
           }
```

Comment: i got a mistake while coping my code. this is the the command:myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT @gb FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor = @ff;";

Answer (score 0):

You need to read more [here](http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet) or [here](http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlcsharptutorial/).

However, I edit your code:

```
    myCommand.CommandText = "SELECT GB,Form_Factor FROM devices WHERE Serial_Number = @Sn";
myCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Sn", Sn);

connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

if (reader.Read())
{
    textBox2.Text = reader["GB"].ToString();
    textBox3.Text = reader["Form_Factor"].ToString();
}
reader.Close();
connect.Close();

string gb = textBox2.Text;
string ff = textBox3.Text;


myCOmmand.CommandText = @"SELECT * FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor = 'Mercury';";

connect.Open();

MySqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

reader2.Read();

if (reader2.Read())
{
    string command = reader2["columnName"].ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(command);
}

if (reader2.Read() == false)
{
    MessageBox.Show("read failed!");
}

reader2.Close();
connect.Close();
```

Make sure to edit reader2["columnName"].TOString(); -> Edit columnName to the columnName you want to get.

Answer (score 0):

1st - you dont need this line:

```
reader2.Read();
```

2nd - `reader2["@gb"].ToString();` is wrong put the ColumnName you need instead of `"@gb"`

3rd - `AddWithValue` make no sense in this fall, you need it only if you have a dynamic variables in your sql-query

EDIT - second part:

```
string gb = textBox2.Text;
string ff = textBox3.Text;
MySqlCommand myCommand2 = connect.CreateCommand();
myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT " + gb + " FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor = @ff;";
myCommand2.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ff", ff);    
connect.Open();
MySqlDataReader reader2 = myCommand2.ExecuteReader();

if (reader2.Read())
{
  string command = reader2[gb].ToString();
  MessageBox.Show(command);
}
else
{
   MessageBox.Show("read failed!");
}

reader2.Close();
connect.Close();
```

Comment: i got a mistake while coping my code. this is the the command:myCommand2.CommandText = "SELECT @gb FROM parameters WHERE Form_Factor = @ff;". gb and ff are the first query results. i want to run the second query with them and i cant